# Code Changes While Debugging Not Taking Effect (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, step-through

I'm stepping through my C# program in Visual Studio, trying to test how a generated HTML string will look given a few modifications. After I pause the debugger, modify my code, then continue, the changes do not take effect. I step through the entire method and when I look at the generated HTML string, it's the same as it was before I modified it. The changes only take effect if I stop running the program and run it again, which is extremely tedious.

Is it caching in some way?

Comment: disable navigator cache or use Ctrl-F5 to force the cache to refresh on the browser

Comment: i'm not sure that would help me here, it's not that i want to refresh without it caching, what i'm doing is, i drag the arrow back up after i generate the html to before i generate it, change the way it's generated, but when i step over again, it's the old one

Comment: Did you try one of the solutions listed in this Stack Overflow  post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266972/visual-studio-edit-and-continue-does-not-work

Comment: Was your project created from an old VS version?

Comment: Well it still doesn't work on occasion, I've tried the responses in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Code Changes While Debugging Not Taking Effect (Visual Studio 2017)

**In fact**, to use that function, every time put the cursor back to the changed part and then step over the cursor, it will take effect.

So please try these suggestions:

**Suggestion**

**1)** make sure that these settings are checked under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`

[image]

uncheck `Require source files to exactly match the original version` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`.

check `Managed` and uncheck `Native` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`Just In Time`

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`,`obj` folder and then restart your project again.

**3)** If you port an existing project, you should specify `EmbedInteropTypes` as `false`.

Add it in `xxxx.csproj` file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
 <EmbedInteropTypes>false</EmbedInteropTypes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**4)** disable any third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extension`

**5)** make sure that you use the **Debug** mode

If your project is created by an old VS version, try to create a new project in VS2017 and then migrate the content of the old project into the new project to test this. (Not sure if the project is created by an old VS version)

**Note** that in different versions of vs, they can be some different, and if it is an old project, it may have some problems with this function in VS2017.

Hope it could help you.