# Visual studio 2013 + .Net 4.5.1 + Edit and continue 64 bit: not working

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, edit-and-continue, .net-4.5

Supposedly vs 2013 added support for edit and continue 64 bit (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/26/debugging-support-for-64-bit-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).

However I can't get it working.

After going to the properties of my .net 4.5.1 asp.net mvc web application project, and checking the "Enable Edit and Continue" checkbox, I can now edit the code while on a breakpoint.

The problem is that after saving and trying to keep on stepping trough, I get an error dialog saying:

> Edits were made which cannot be compiled. Execution cannot continue
>   until compile errors are fixed

In the error list window, those 2 errors always show:

> The type 'System.IEquatable`1' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> The type 'System.ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

It's really weird error message right? However insignificant my change is, I always get the same error.

note: I run windows 7 / vs 2013 ultimate and my project is set up to use IIS Express in the project properties.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a known issue when referencing portable libraries and using Edit & Continue. We are looking to fix this in a future version of Visual Studio.

A workaround for now:

1. Right-click on the project with the issue in **Solution Explorer** and choose **Unload**
2. Right-click on the unloaded project and choose **Edit**
3. Within the body of the first `<PropertyGroup>` element, add the following: `<_ResolveReferenceDependencies>true</_ResolveReferenceDependencies>`
4. Reload the project saving changes

This should fix the build issue.

**Note:** Depending on the project, this *might* have a performance hit, not only during Edit & Continue usage, but just general usage within VS.

Comment: Thank you, that did fix it. I gotta guess that's a pretty common scenario these days with most projects pulling nuget packages. In my case I believe the RX package uses portable libraries...

Comment: Fixed it for me too. I added a reference to your answer here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763241/edit-and-continue-failes-to-compile#tabs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only solution that worked was to remove the workspace and map&get again.

To remove the workspace, `Source control` → `Advanced` → `Workspace` → `Remove`.