# Live edit of code not working in .NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am creating a Windows application targeting .NET 4.5.1. It compiles and runs fine. When I hit the break-point and edit the source code, I get the message saying:

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have latest Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack installed and using VS 2013.

I have tried to manually reference the System.Runtime.dll, but then my project does not even compile, with the compiler complaining:

> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1'
>   does not contain a definition for 'IsCompleted'

I can find similar error reports for ASP.NET but nothing for Windows applications. Is there something I can do to get the editing of the running source code working again?

Comment: Why would you edit the code while the application is running?

Comment: @jmc ; Don't you know the [Edit&Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx) feature ?

Comment: to fix a bug for example @jmc

Comment: I've seen this a few times in SO questions, the underlying cause is still very murky.  Nobody lists their dependencies or posts a minimum repro so very hard to reverse-engineer.  Go through the References node of the project and mention any unusual dependencies.  If you use a Nuget package then be sure to name it.  Also look at their Path property, anything from c:\windows\microsoft.net instead of c:\program files\reference assemblies is a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I have bare minimal repro project where I get same issue, I'll post it to the GitHub.

Comment: To reproduce this error:
1) checkout https://github.com/justas-/so-31851536; 
2) add breakpoint in MainWindow.xaml.cs line 32. 
3) Start app, click button
4) When VS breaks, change the line 33 to something valid
5) Clicking will cause the error to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try also to add a reference to:

- `System.Threading.dll`
- `System.Threading.Tasks.dll`

Comment: Just found this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324080/visual-studio-2013-net-4-5-1-edit-and-continue-64-bit-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, adding these references fixed it, but it still looks more like a workarround instead of actual fix.

Comment: can you migrate to visual studio 2015. the things you can do in edit & continue mode is quiet more impressive than 2013. maybe this solves also your issue (hoever I had some other side effects in 2015 that i didn't have in 2013)