# VS2015 Pro - Changes to MVC views not reflecting during debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

Until earlier this week I have been able to make changes to my `.cshtml` Razor views while debugging my application and see the changes when I refreshed the page. Now, all of a sudden, the changes are not reflected until I stop debugging and rebuild.

I haven't made any changes in the past week or so that I can think of, to include adding any new NuGet packages.

Edit and Continue is enabled under Tools => Options => Debugging. Also, I'm using VS2015 Professional so IntelliTrace wouldn't be getting in the way.

I have tried the following solutions from [another question about Edit and Continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782057/edit-and-continue-feature-stopped-working-in-visual-studio-2010) but none have worked for me.

- Close and reopen the solution;
- Restart Visual Studio;
- Make sure I'm not using `dynamic` method parameters;
- Delete the `bin` and `obj` folders along with the `.suo` file in the `.vs` folder then restart Visual Studio;
- Updated all of the NuGet packages for the solution;
- Ensure `<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>` is nowhere in my solution;
- Run `VsPerfCLREnv /globaloff`.

Comment: What is the build action of your views set to?

Comment: @DavidG The build action is "Content".

Comment: After doing a bit of poking around, it turns out that everything works fine if I'm working from the solution folder on my local machine. The problem only seems to presents itself when I copy the solution to a network share and work on it from there.

Comment: Oh dear, don't ever do that!